# Deleting directories and sub-directories

Tags: php, function, directory, delete-file

I have a small issue regarding a function that I've created. It should delete every directories and sub-directories (and of course, the files in it) but it does absolutely nothing!

```
function deletedirandfiles($data, $username){

                //$data correspond au chemin clé, cad à images/users

                $dir = opendir($data); // On définit le répertoire dans lequel on souhaite travailler.

                while (false !== ($fichier = readdir($dir))) // On lit chaque fichier du répertoire dans la boucle.
                {
                    if (($fichier == '.') OR ($fichier == '..') OR ($fichier == '.DS_Store') OR ($fichier != $username)){
                    // On ne fait rien pour ne pas les afficher
                    }

                    elseif (is_file($data.'/'.$fichier)){
                        unlink($data.'/'.$fichier);
                    }

                    elseif (is_dir($data.'/'.$fichier)){
                        $foldertoworkin = "$data/$fichier";
                        deletedirandfiles($foldertoworkin, $username); //On lance la recursivité en reappelant la fonction
                        rmdir($data.'/'.$fichier);
                    }

                    else{

                    }

                }

                closedir($dir);

}
```

In this case: $data = "images/users" and $username = the name of the folder.

Any idea why it does not work ?

Comment: specify a language, it will help people to answer your question, based on language knowledge

Comment: I assumed PHP, if not retag your question

Comment: Yes, sorry, it is PHP. Thanks for the tag.

Comment: You want something like this? `shell_exec('rm -rf /some/dir/*');`

Comment: I'm sorry but what is this ?

Comment: Read more about [shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rm_(Unix))...

Comment: @TheJailbreakBay this using a shell command

Answer (score 0):

An OS agnostic solution that works with hidden files can be:

```
public static function delTree($dir) { 
    $files = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('.','..')); 
    foreach ($files as $file) { 
      (is_dir("$dir/$file")) ? delTree("$dir/$file") : unlink("$dir/$file"); 
    } 
    return rmdir($dir); 
}
```

You can find more examples at: https://www.php.net/rmdir

Regards.